# Javascript Unable to GetElementById in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, events, onclick

I know this is a very common problem.  I was trying to get a "enter key" event to invoke a click on a certain button on the page through javascript.  However,  I can't for the life of me fetch a single element by its id or name from my asp.net page.

It is my understanding that this issue is related to where the javascript is located and whether the elements have been rendered by the time the javascript is loaded or something of that nature?

Every time I attempt to use `var x = document.getElementById('btn_AddAdmin')` I end up with a null value.

My asp.net page has SiteMaster page that it inherits from.  I have included a trimmed down version of my asp.net page and the SiteMaster page.

ASP.NET Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
     AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="HERMES.Admin" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<input type="text" id="txt_AddAdmin" runat="server" onkeypress="Populate()" />
```

Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" 
         Inherits="HERMES.SiteMaster" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="./Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
</form>
</body>
```

Sorry for the formatting, I seem to be doing something wrong...

I have attempted placing the javascript in many different locations -- anywhere from the sitemaster page to the top and bottom of my asp.net page.  No luck either way.

Comment: To answer your first question, yes, the position of document.getElementById does matter. You need to call this after the element with the id "btn_AddAdmin" has been rendered by the web browser or when you know the dom is ready. It is not clear from your question where you include your javascript. All I can see is that the function "Populate()" is called when text is entered into the input with the id txt_AddAdmin. I suggest you post the source code of your rendered html page here. Perhaps use http://jsfiddle.net/ to make things easier.

Comment: I have attempted relocating the javascript code all over the place as per the last line in my comment and it was not working regardless.  However, @Xander has covered what the problem was.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var x = document.getElementById('<%= btn_AddAdmin.ClientID %>');
```

If your button is a `Server Control` it prepends a naming scheme to the `input` button so it can be bound back to the appropriate server control during `postback`. Thus the need to use the `ClientID` property to retrieve the "rendered id".

To learn more visit:

- http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/client-script,-jquery,-and-ajax
- http://www.asp.net/

Google it with Bing:

- clientid
- aspnet webforms client side programming

Comment: Wow that actually worked.  Why does this approach work and not the other?

Comment: @ImGreg - The `id` attribute on a server side control (one with a `runat="server"` attribute) means the _server side_ ID of the control, to be used by code behind C#. The `ClientId` property for such controls is the emitted `id` as it would appear in the browser for consumption by javascript.

Comment: Gottcha.  That makes sense.  However, I clearly need to read more into this to get a better understanding of how this stuff works.  Any links for some relevant readings?  Thanks again btw.

Comment: "button so it can be bound back to the appropriate server control during postback"  The ID is not sent on postback, the name attribute is.  Although it is correct that both the name and ID are mangled, in a similar (but slightly different) fashion.

Comment: @Matthew wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/

Comment: @Xander, Can you think of anything off the top of your head that would cause the onclick to fail (only in IE) if it is invoked from the javascript using getelementbyid().click()?  Or should I start a new question for this?

Comment: @imgreg `getElementById().click = function() { __doPostBack('<%= btn_AddAdmin.ClientID %>', ''); };`

Comment: @Xander sorry I deleted my comment (wasn't quite correct, again).  The ID attributes have the logical sections separated by underscores, while the posted value in __EventTarget and other post values is separated by dollar signs.  Input type fields use the the dollar sign format for their name attributes, while LinkButtons do not have a "name" attribute, they still post using the dollar sign format.